# Is there any theoretical results about the determinants of a Non-Central Wishart matrix?

Tags: random-matrices

As we know that a Non-Central Wishart matrix is defined as
$W:=XX^T$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times N}$, and
$X:= M + E$, with $M \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times N}$ a deterministic and non-zero matrix, and each element of $E$ obeying the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.
While on the contrary, the Central Wishart matrix can be viewed as a special case of the Non-Central one when $M=0$ as shown above.
My question is, is there any theoretical result about the determinant of this Non-Central Wishart matrix $W$? i.e., what do we know about
$det(W)=det((M+E)(M+E)^T)$
e.g. do we know about the expectation, the moment or even the concentration inequalily about this random determinant?
And what is the relationship of the determinant between Non-Central Wishart matrices and central Wishart matrices?

Answer (score 2):

For more on the determinants Noncentral Wishart Matrices see Muirhead (1982,2005) Chapter 10. In particular see [Theorem 10.3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OHs.png). Muirhead also argues that the moments of the determinant can be used to obtain asymptotic distributions in builds towards this in his problems [10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ht1.png) 10.3 and 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

upper and lower bounds for the expectation of $\log\det W$ --- with complex matrix elements, but I presume readily generalized to real matrix elements --- have been derived in [On the log-determinant of noncentral Wishart matrices](http://circuit.ucsd.edu/~yhk/pdfs/isit2003.pdf) (2003):

if the real eigenvalues of $\sigma^{-2}MM^{\ast}$ are ordered from large to small, $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\cdots\geq\lambda_p$, then

$$g_N(\lambda_1)+\sum_{k=2}^{p}\psi(N-k+1)\leq E(\log\det W)-p\log\sigma^2\leq\sum_{k=1}^p g_N(\lambda_k)$$

$${\rm with}\;\;g_N(\lambda)=\log\lambda-{\rm Ei}\,(-\lambda)+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(-1/\lambda)^k\left[e^{-\lambda}(k-1)!-\frac{(N-1)!}{k(N-1-k)!}\right]$$

and $\psi$ the digamma function, Ei the exponential integral. Equality in the lower bound iff $\lambda_k=0$ for $k>1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm still wondering if there is any further result about this log determinant random variable $\log\det W$? e.g., the distribution, or something like the confidence interval about this log determinant?